# How to create a setup on installShield to install two programs

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, installation, installshield

I'd like to create a setup using InstallShield. This setup must install on the pc the Framework .NET 40fx, and after this, install one application that developed in C#.

I have the framework setup, and my applications setup too.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using installShield 2009 I don't have the option of .Net 4.0 like a redistributable, so I resolved this question inserting a prerequisite. it's easy and worked.

Check it out:

http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is install your application along with its various prerequisites.

In the InstallShield IDE, click on "Redistributables".  Here you will find merge modules for many many prerequisites.  (if .NET 4.0 isn't in the list, use the InstallShield updater to download it)

There are a few options relating to how redistributables are handled.  See here for more info:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IncludingRedistributables.htm